# Commutation relation of $P^{\mu}$ with fermion field $\psi(x)$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spacetime, momentum, symmetry, conventions

On Giunti and Kim's book "Fundamentals of neutrino physics and astrophysics", page 38-39, the book is trying to derive the commutation relation of $P^{\mu}$ and $\psi(x)$.

Begin with:
$$ U\psi(x)U^{\dagger}=\psi^{\prime}(x)=\psi(x-a) , \tag{2.285} $$
where $U$ is a unitary transformation, with infinitesimal form
$$ U = 1+i\varepsilon b_{\mu} P^{\mu}, \tag{2.280}$$
so $P^{\mu}$ is the generator of space-time translation.

From (2.280) and L.H.S of (2.285), we can get
$$ \psi^{\prime}(x)=\psi(x)+i \varepsilon b_\mu\left[\mathrm{P}^\mu, \psi(x)\right]. \tag{2.281}$$
where we only keep the term linear in $\varepsilon$.

On the other hand, from the R.H.S of (2.285), we can get
$$ \psi^{\prime}(x)=\psi(x)- \varepsilon b_\mu \partial^\mu \psi(x). \tag{2.282}$$
where we replace $a$ with parameter $\varepsilon b_\mu$, and their have a typo of $i$ in the book, we omit it.

So if we compare (2.281) and (2.282), we will get
$$\left[\mathrm{P}^\mu, \psi(x)\right]=i \partial^\mu \psi(x) $$
However, the book have a sign difference with my analysis, the book give
$$\left[\mathrm{P}^\mu, \psi(x)\right]=-i \partial^\mu \psi(x) \tag{2.283}$$

So that's going wrong with this minus sign?

Comment: Equation (2.280) corresponds to the transformation $\psi(x)\to\psi(x+a)$. Check for example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_operator_(quantum_mechanics)

Comment: Fermion is irrelevant. It works the same for bosons.

Comment: @Nothingham the example you give is about transformation about state, here is about transformation about operator. Where $\psi(x)$ is already after second quantization, is composed of creation and annihilation operator.

Comment: @Qmechanic As the book said, for bosons case, their don't have a minus sign in eq.(2.283).

Comment: What I meant is that you're suppose to define $U=e^{-ix\cdot p}$ $(\hbar=1)$. Expand this and you'll get your negative sign.